# need help for my parts in snapcraft.yaml

Tags: snap

Am trying to add these packages as parts for my snap :

- PHP7 (of course will need apache2) 
    && (libapache2-mod-php5 \
              php7.0-mcrypt \
              php7.0-curl \
              php7.0-gd  \
              php7.0-cli \
              php7.0-cgi \
              php7.0-imagick \
              php7.0-common \
              php7.0-imap \
              php7.0-json \
              php7.0-readline \
              php7.0-sqlite \
              php7.0-xcache \
              php7.0-mysql);
- openssh-server
- sendmail
- default-jdk
- maven2
- unzip
- mysql-client
- nagios-plugins
- nagios-nrpe-server

If You can help me please what should i declare in parts of my snapcraft.yaml file (i mean source, sourcetype, plugin ...)

Answer (score 0):

Add all the packages whose contents you want shipped as part of your snap in `stage-packages:`.

Take a look at https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen for some more apps and how they were put together.